# PDO rollback doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$myServer='127.0.0.1';
$myDB='karma';
$myUser='root';
$myPass='wilian';


try {
    $connStr = "mysql:host=".$myServer.";dbname=".$myDB; 
    $dbh = new PDO($connStr,$myUser,$myPass);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die("Unable to connect: " . $e->getMessage());
}

try {  
  $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $dbh->beginTransaction();
  $dbh->query("insert into mst_goods_category (id, GOODS_CATEGORY_CODE, GOODS_CATEGORY_NAME, ACTIVE_FLAG, CREATE_DATE, CREATE_TIME, CREATE_USER) values (12, '012', '333', 'Y', '20140702', '00:00:00', 'admin')");
  $dbh->query("insert into mst_goods_category (id, GOODS_CATEGORY_CODE, GOODS_CATEGORY_NAME, ACTIVE_FLAG, CREATE_DATE, CREATE_TIME, CREATE_USER) values (13, '012', '333', 'Y', '20140702', '00:00:00', 'admin')");
  $dbh->commit();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
  $dbh->rollBack();
  throw $e;
}
```

Second query is error, because of unique constraint..
throw $e is appear, but it doest not rollback, any one know whats wrong?

Comment: why do you think it should be rolled back?

Comment: It should only rollback if something went wrong

Comment: oh im sorry, second query is error, because unique constraint

Comment: which constraint is unique? what error do you get? what engine table mst_goods_category is created on?

Comment: field GOODS_CATEGORY_CODE is PK, error messages is "Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry". im sorry, what is the mean engine to create table? i'm personally use aqua data studio to handle all my query. and i use xampp for mysql and apache.. Thank you

Comment: okay. and the last question?

Comment: run `show create table mst_goods_category` query and see what does it say after `ENGINE=`

Comment: it said "ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1"

Comment: by the way, most likely you want to change CHARSET as well. but don't do it the same way as engine!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are using Myisam engine that doesn't support transactions. change it to InnoDB

```
ALTER TABLE mst_goods_category ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: While this is something to check, doesn't PDO emulate transactions for DBs that don't support them natively?

Comment: I do "ALTER TABLE mst_goods_category ENGINE=InnoDB;"
but when i see create table, its still MyISAM.. any suggest? Thank you before. sorry for bad english

Comment: it said " Warnings: ---> 
   W (1): Using storage engine MyISAM for table 'mst_goods_category'
          <--- 

 21 record(s) affected 

 [Executed: 4/12/14 11:34:37 AM GMT ] [Execution: 235/ms] "

Comment: then run `show engines` and see if innodb supported. But it's hardly believable in 2014, if you won't find it. It seems you need to upgrade your software.

Comment: oh my god, innodb is DISABLED :D OK i will download something new